# Undo ignore word in Kile

Tags: kile, spelling, dictionaries

I have accidentally selected "ignore" for a misspelled word in Kile.
I cannot find in the doc or in forums how I can undo it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make the mistakely ignored word an ignored word (worth the redundancy):

<kbd>Settings</kbd> > 
<kbd>Configure Kile</kbd> > 
<kbd>Editing</kbd> > 
<kbd>Spellcheck</kbd> > 
<kbd>Ignored word</kbd> > Write  `vurro` (for instance) 
<kbd>**+ Add**</kbd> 
<kbd>OK</kbd>

2) Unmake it an ignored word:

<kbd>Settings</kbd> > 
 
<kbd>Configure Kile</kbd> > 
<kbd>Editing</kbd> > 
<kbd>Spellcheck</kbd> > 
<kbd>Ignored word</kbd> > Write  `vurro`  (again)  
 <kbd>**- Remove**</kbd>  
<kbd>OK</kbd>

Annoyingly, it seems that you can not take the second step without giving the first.